# Stopping index of Github pages

Tags: robots.txt, github-pages

I have a github page from my repository   username.github.io

However I do not want Google to crawl my website and absolutely do not want it to show up on search results.

Will just using robots.txt in github pages work?     I know there are tutorials for stop indexing Github repository but what about  the actual Github page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Will just using robots.txt in github pages work?

If you're using the default GitHub Pages subdomain, then no because Google would check `https://github.io/robots.txt` only.

You can make sure [you don't have a `master` branch, or that your GitHub repo is a private one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15987482/6309), although, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784322/stopping-index-of-github-pages/32805279?noredirect=1#comment82263490_32805279) by [olavimmanuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243045/olavimmanuel) and detailed in olavimmanuel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47652485/6309), this would not change anything.

However, if you're using a [custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) with your GitHub Pages site, you can place a robots.txt file at the root of your repo and it will work as expected.  One example of using this pattern is the repo for [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/).

However, [bmaupin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399105/bmaupin) points out, from [Google's own documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro):

> A `robots.txt` file tells search engine crawlers which URLs the crawler can access on your site.
>
> This is used mainly to avoid overloading your site with requests; it is *not* a mechanism for keeping a web page out of Google.
>
> To keep a web page out of Google, [block indexing with `noindex`](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/block-indexing) or password-protect the page."

Comment: Actually, it seems that placing `robots.txt` in a subdomain will [work](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt#examples-of-valid-robotstxt-urls) according to Google's documentation, unless it's severely outdated. I've noticed a lot of web developers who use Github Pages and Jekyll to create their blogs that have `robots.txt` in their repositories even if they don't use custom domains. I haven't verified that this works, but it seems the evidence is in favor of it working as intended, at least for Google's crawler.

Comment: Thank you VonC, I am using github.io domain, I only have a master branch and my repo is public. But I still cannot search my blog from google? Is there anything else I have to confirm?

Comment: "I still cannot search my blog from google": this question is about *not* searching a blog through Google. So it seems to be working in your case.

Comment: @VonC I don't believe making "sure you don't have a master branch, or that your GitHub repo is a private one" will make a difference to GitHub Pages, just the repository.
According to GitHubs Help: ["Pages are always publicly accessible when published, even if their repository is private."](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/)
A Project Page can be published from a [variety of sources](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/). It would be weird if the existence of a master brach affected robots.txt or meta tags.

Comment: For now `https://github.io/robots.txt` is redirected to `https://pages.github.com/` and does not work.

Comment: From [Google's own documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro): "A robots.txt file tells search engine crawlers which URLs the crawler can access on your site. This is used mainly to avoid overloading your site with requests; it is not a mechanism for keeping a web page out of Google. To keep a web page out of Google, [block indexing with `noindex`](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/block-indexing) or password-protect the page."

Answer (score 33):

I don't know if it is still relevant, but [google says](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en) you can stop spiders with a `meta` tag:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

I'm not sure however if that works for all spiders or google only.

Comment: This is super useful when you don't have root access to the server, as in the case of Github pages. Thanks @Gumbo!

Answer (score 14):

#### Short answer:

You can use a [robots.txt](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt) to stop indexing of your users GitHub Pages by adding it in your [User Page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/). This robots.txt will be the active robots.txt for all your projects pages as the project pages are reachable as subdirectories (username.github.io/**project**) in your subdomain (**username**.github.io).

---

#### Longer answer:

You get your own subdomain for GitHub pages (username.github.io). According to [this](https://moz.com/community/q/robots-txt-on-subdomains) question on MOZ and [googles reference](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt#examples-of-valid-robotstxt-urls) each subdomain has/needs its own `robots.txt`.

This means that the valid/active robots.txt for project `projectname` by user `username` lives at `username.github.io/robots.txt`. You can put a `robots.txt`file there by creating a GitHub Pages page for your user.

This is done by creating a new project/repository named `username.github.io` where `username` is your username. You can now create a robots.txt file in the master branch of this project/repository and it should be visible at `username.github.io/robots.txt`. More information about project, user and organization pages can be found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/).

I have tested this with Google, confirming ownership of `myusername.github.io` by placing a html file in my project/repository `https://github.com/myusername/myusername.github.io/tree/master`, creating a robot.txt file there and then verifying that my robots.txt works by using Googles Search Console [webmaster tools (googlebot-fetch)](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch). Google does indeed list it as blocked and Google Search Console [webmaster tools (robots-testing-tool)](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool) confirms it.

To block robots for one projects GitHub Page:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /projectname/
```

To block robots for all GitHub Pages for your user (User Page and all Project Pages):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

---

#### Other options

- Look into the HTML [meta](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robots-meta-directives) tag
- Look into [custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) ([redirects](https://help.github.com/articles/custom-domain-redirects-for-github-pages-sites/)) for GitHub Pages

Answer (score 5):

Google doesn't recommend using a robots.txt file to not index a website(GitHub page in this case). In fact most of the time it does get indexed even if you block the google bot.

Instead, you should add the following in your page head, which should be easy to control even if you are not using a custom domain.

```
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' />
```

This will tell Google to NOT index it. Where if you only block google bot to access your website it will still index like 90% of the time just won't show meta description.

Comment: Hi and thanks for this updated info about how it works in practice! Is this related to only blocking the google bot or all blocking via robots.txt?  
Do you have a source for this Google recommendation?

Comment: Here is a video from Google Webmasters official youtube channel. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBdEwpRQRD0