# What's the best way to write robots.txt for github pages using multiple repos?

Tags: jekyll, sitemap, github-pages, robots.txt

I am using Github pages to build my personal website with Jekyll. I have a head site in the `username.github.io` repo, project A site in the `projectA` repo, project B in the `projectB` repo and so on. I have put a `CNAME` file under the `username.github.io` repo so that all of my sites are under the customized domain name (`www.mydomain.com`). I have noticed that with `robots.txt` file pointing to the `sitemap.txt` file under each repo, the `sitemap.txt` can only contain page links for pages in each separate repo. So, I have a couple of questions:

1. Since my site is structured as `www.mydomain.com`, `www.mydomain.com/projectA`, `www.mydomain.com/projectB` and so on corresponding to the pages in single repos, will the search engine recognize all of my site pages even though the `sitemap.txt` under the `username.github.io` head repo only has the page links generated in the single repo?
2. What is the best way to write the `robots.txt` file in my case?

Thanks!
Qi

Answer (score 3):

### Standards and disclaimer

`Sitemap:` in robots.txt is a nonstandard extension [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard). Remember that:

> [Using the Sitemap protocol does not guarantee that web pages are included in search engines, but provides hints for web crawlers to do a better job of crawling your site.](https://www.sitemaps.org/index.html)

Wikipedia also lists `allow:` as a nonstandard extension.

### Multiple sitemaps in robots.txt

[You can specify more than one Sitemap file per robots.txt file.](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#submit_robots) When specifying more than one sitemap in robots.txt this is the format:

```
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap-host1.xml

Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap-host2.xml
```

### An index of sitemaps

There is also a type of sitemap file that is an [index of sitemap files](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index).

> If you have a Sitemap index file, you can include the location of just that file. You don't need to list each individual Sitemap listed in the index file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

   <sitemap>

      <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap1.xml.gz</loc>

      <lastmod>2004-10-01T18:23:17+00:00</lastmod>

   </sitemap>

   <sitemap>

      <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap2.xml.gz</loc>

      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>

   </sitemap>

</sitemapindex>
```

`<lastmod>` is optional.

### About excluding content

> The Sitemaps protocol enables you to let search engines know what content you would like indexed. To tell search engines the content you don't want indexed, use a robots.txt file or robots meta tag. See robotstxt.org for more information on how to exclude content from search engines.

If you want search engines not to index anything it should be in the robots.txt file (in the User Page repository) as:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /project_to_disallow/
Disallow: /projectname/page_to_disallow.html
```

Alternatively you can use the [robots tag](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robots-meta-directives).

### Suggestions

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /project_to_disallow/
Disallow: /projectname/page_to_disallow.html

Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml

Sitemap: http://www.example.com/projectA/sitemap.xml

Sitemap: http://www.example.com/projectB/sitemap.xml
```

or, if you are using a sitemap index file

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /project_to_disallow/
Disallow: /projectname/page_to_disallow.html

Sitemap: http://www.example.com/siteindex.xml
```

where `http://www.example.com/siteindex.xml` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

   <sitemap>

      <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml</loc>

   </sitemap>

   <sitemap>

      <loc>http://www.example.com/projectA/sitemap.xml</loc>

   </sitemap>

   <sitemap>

      <loc>http://www.example.com/projectB/sitemap.xml</loc>

   </sitemap>

</sitemapindex>
```

---

For info on how set up robots.txt with GitHub Pages see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47652485/243045).

Answer (score 1):

> Where to put it The short answer: in the top-level directory of your
>   web server. 
>   *Source : http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html*

You can also read in [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt) that a www.mydomain.com/folder/robots.txt url will not be crawled.

The basic www.mydomain.com/robots.txt can be :

```
User-agent: *
```

This will instruct crawler to thru all www.mydomain.com file hierarchy by following links.

If no page of www.mydomain.com is referencing you project pages, you can add :

```
User-agent: *
allow: /ProjectA
allow: /projectB
```

Comment: I have special rules for each Project repo, and I put those allowed links under the `sitemap.txt` file under each project repo. Can I use something like `sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.txt; sitemap: https://www.example.com/ProjectA/sitemap.txt; sitemap: https://www.example.com/ProjectB/sitemap.txt` (in three lines of course)? In this way, I don't need to update the top-level repo if there is any robot rule was changed under a project repo. Thank you for replying.