# How do I make my github.io page appear above my github.io repository in google?

Tags: seo, github-pages

So yeah I think the title says it all here, but if you google the url of my github.io page (krewn.github.io) the first link is the repo, the second link is the commit history and then third is my github.io page... As of right now my meta tags are as follows:

```
    <title>Kevin Nelson</title>

    <!-- Standards !-->
    <meta charset="utf-8"><!-- html5 version of http-equiv="Content-Type"... -->
    <meta name="description" content="The personal web page of Kevin Nelson 11/16/93">
    <meta name="keywords" content="developer programming code script ">
    <link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/+KevinNelsonBrewster" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://krewn.github.io/" />

    <!-- For Google !-->
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Kevin Nelson">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="The personal web page of Kevin Nelson 11/16/93">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="https://krewn.github.io/ApophysisOutPuts/Origin/adbgPostPost.jpg">

    <!-- For Facebook !-->
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://krewn.github.io/">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://krewn.github.io/ApophysisOutPuts/Origin/adbgPostPost.jpg">
    <meta property="og:description" content="The personal web page of Kevin Nelson 11/16/93">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Kevin Nelson">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="krewn io">
    <meta property="og:see_also" content="https://krewn.github.io">

    <!-- For Twitter !-->
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="The personal web page of Kevin Nelson 11/16/93">
    <meta name="twitter:url" content="https://krewn.github.io">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Kevin Nelson">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="The personal web page of Kevin Nelson 11/16/93">
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://krewn.github.io/ApophysisOutPuts/Origin/adbgPostPost.jpg">
```

**EDIT::** Obviously there is no button to press to tell Google how to order their results, but any input on how to make it more likely that my page appears first when the URL is searched would be great. For example would putting the URL in the description help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

Google determines the rankings for a particular query using their own proprietary algorithms.

Comment: If this isn't a valid question SEO isn't a valid industry.

Comment: @kpie First, SEO firms are typically able to put code on the pages you're trying to affect. Here you're trying to derank stuff on Github.com (the repo / commit history) where you can't modify the HTML. If you were able to add a `rel="canonical"` meta tag on the repo page, this would be easy, but you can't.

Comment: @kpie Second, if you ask me, SEO is barely "a valid industry". It's full of snake oil and bad actors.

Comment: Thanks for the info, and the laughs.

Comment: It is not possible to prevent google from indexing a master branch. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844905/how-to-stop-google-indexing-my-github-repository