# Do search engines index my code located in a GitHub repository?

Tags: github, web-crawler, search-engine, google-crawlers

I want to make a repository public, however, I want to hide some information from search engines, which is located in that repository.

My repository has a file called `imprint.html`, which contains my address and full name. I do not want that my GitHub account or the GitHub repository shows up after someone searches for my name or address.

The HTML file contains the following meta-element in its head: `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">`. This works fine when the website is deployed, my website will not show up when e.g. googling my name or address.

I'm aware of solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844905/how-to-stop-google-indexing-my-github-repository), which will hide the complete GitHub repository from search engines. However, I am fine with my GitHub repository showing up, when searching for its name. I just want that it does not show up when searching for information located in the `imprint.html` file.

I am imagining three possible scenarios that could happen:

1. Search Engines take the meta-element mentioned above into account, even in an HTML file located in a GitHub repository.
2. Code from a GitHub repository is not indexed at all.
3. I'll have to delete the file from my complete commit history before making the repository public.

How can I hide the specific file in my repository from Google or other search engines?

Comment: Github is no mean to store private information. If you declare it on Github publicly, be ready to see it on public.

Comment: @HuyPhạm It is not really private information, after all, the data is available on my website. I just want that my GitHub profile does not directly pop up when searching for my address or my name.